# Perl 6 multi methods never match expected signature

Tags: oop, raku, method-signature, multimethod

I have a class with two multi methods (`multi submit`).

I call my multi like this:

```
$perspective.submit(:message($message.content));
```

Which gets shipped off to my class:

```
my $perspective-api = API::Perspective.new(:api-key(%*ENV<PERSPECTIVE_API_KEY>));

proto method submit (|) {*}

multi method submit(Str :$message!, MODEL :@models = TOXICITY) {
    my $score = $perspective-api.analyze(:@models, :comment($message));
    say @models Z=> $score<attributeScores>{@models}.map: *<summaryScore><value>;

multi method submit(Str :$name!, MODEL :@models = TOXICITY) {
    my $score = $perspective-api.analyze(:@models, :comment($name));
    say @models Z=> $score<attributeScores>{@models}.map: *<summaryScore><value>;
}
```

However I always get the following response:

```
Died because of the exception:
    Cannot resolve caller AUTOGEN(Rose::ContentAnalysis::Perspective:D: :message(Str)); none of these signatures match:
        (Rose::ContentAnalysis::Perspective: Str :$message!, MODEL :@models = MODEL::TOXICITY, *%_)
        (Rose::ContentAnalysis::Perspective: Str :$name!, MODEL :@models = MODEL::TOXICITY, *%_)
```

Despite my named argument (`:message`) being a `Str` as required and `@models` having a default declared.

Comment: Could you share the definition of `TOXICITY`? I'm wondering if your default value is impossible to assign.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington you can find the MODEL enum within my `API::Perspective` module here, if that is what you are looking for. https://github.com/shuppet/p6-api-perspective/blob/master/lib/API/Perspective.pm6#L32-L37

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiple dispatch works in two phases:

- Considering the number of positional parameters and their types
- If there are any `where` clauses, named parameters, or sub-signatures, doing a test bind of the signature to see if it would match

The second phase will reject the candidate if it fails to bind for any reason. One such reason, and I believe the cause of the issue here, is that the default value is wrongly typed. For example, in:

```
multi m(:@x = "not-an-array") { }
m()
```

We get an error:

```
Cannot resolve caller m(...); none of these signatures match:
    (:@x = "not-an-array")
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

But changing it to:

```
multi m(:@x = ["an-array"]) { }
m()
```

Works fine. (Note that while a default value uses `=`, it's actually a binding, not an assignment.)

In the case in the question there's this:

```
MODEL :@models = TOXICITY
```

Looking at the module source the code is taken from, I see:

```
enum MODEL is export (
        <TOXICITY SEVERE_TOXICITY TOXICITY_FAST IDENTITY_ATTACK
        INSULT PROFANITY SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT THREAT FLIRTATION
        ATTACK_ON_AUTHOR ATTACK_ON_COMMENTER INCOHERENT INFLAMMATORY
        LIKELY_TO_REJECT OBSCENE SPAM UNSUBSTANTIAL>
);
```

Thus TOXICITY is just an `Int`, but what's expected is a typed array of `MODEL` values.

Thus, if you do this:

```
multi method submit(Str :$message!, MODEL :@models = Array[MODEL](TOXICITY)) {
```

It should work.

Answer (score 8):

I see two issues.

One is that you have two methods that are identical except for the name of one named parameter.

Named parameters can have aliases:

```perl6
#                       V--------------V
multi method submit(Str :name(:$message)!, MODEL :@models = TOXICITY) {
    my $score = $perspective-api.analyze(:@models, :comment($message));
    say @models Z=> $score<attributeScores>{@models}.map: *<summaryScore><value>;
}
```

Note that `:$message` is really short for `:message($message)`

---

Now on the problem which actually prevents your code from working.

`@models` is a *Positional*, but you are assigning it a singular value in the signature.

Assign it a *Positional*, and it works:
(In this case it has to be of type `Array[MODEL]` because of the `MODEL` type declaration.)

```perl6
#                                                           V---------------------V
multi method submit(Str :name(:$message)!, MODEL :@models = Array[MODEL](TOXICITY,)) {
    my $score = $perspective-api.analyze(:@models, :comment($message));
    say @models Z=> $score<attributeScores>{@models}.map: *<summaryScore><value>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Brad, Jonathan's solution actually solved my core issue but I think you did a good job pointing out code that is probably going to bite me further down the line so I'll take these suggestions into consideration too. :)

Comment: @raiph I tried a much smaller subset of the problem when I was testing.

Comment: Hi Brad. But... **Named parameter alias** Are you saying your mention of the named parameter alias aspect should now be understood as purely about possibility for a reader of the code being confused? Or did you see an instance in which things went wrong in your tests? Or foresee a problem even though you didn't see one in your tests? **`Array[Model]`** Do you concur that the key issue with the OP is that a `Bar @baz` parameter or similar must be bound to a `Foo[Bar]` argument, where `Foo` does `Positional`? Perhaps the answers to my questions are obvious to some but not to me. TIA for a reply.